# x.strip() with for in python

Tags: python, split

I have a python line which is :

```
start_codon=[x.strip()
             for x in start_codon.split(",")]
```

can anybody explain what is the use of x.strip() combined with the "for"
I can see that the result of just doing start_codon.split(",") will be the same as writing the entire line

Comment: Please add some sample data for `start_codon`.

Comment: I would believe there's a `','.join()` missing to probably get the clean text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `strip()` method removes both the leading and the trailing spaces.

If you have a string such as:

```
string = ' ATGC, TGC , ATGC'
```

Then `string.split(',')` gives:

```
[' ATGC',' TGC ',' ATGC']
```

If you want to split and strip at the same time, then you do:

```
lst = [x.strip() for x in start_codon.split(",")]
```

And so you get:

```
['ATGC','TGC','ATGC']
```

Comment: I understad, basically it says that for every x in the string with x meaning an element will split the string and remove the white spaces, I got it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

split(',') used for separate the string from colon are whatever you provide in split function.

example:

```
hobbies = 'x, y, z, p'
print(hobbies.split(','))

# output - ['x', 'y', 'z', 'p']
```

strip() is used to remove whitespaces from both sides of the given input.

example:

```
name = '    sagar     '
print(name.strip())

# output - sagar
```

the output by strip() does not contain the whitespaces.

In your case, you got the same output by just split() because your string or input does not contain the extra unneccasaary whitespaces.

but the use of strip() is the most ideal and best practice with the code.

now here is the example of strip() with split()

```
data = '    x1     ,    y1     ,      z1       '
print(data.split(','))

# output = ['    x1     ', '    y1     ', '      z1       ']

newData = [x.strip() for x in data.split(",")]
print(newData)

# output = ['x1', 'y1', 'z1']
```

Answer (score 0):

We can see what the [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method does in the docs.

> ```
> str.strip([chars])
> ```
>
> Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed. ... If omitted or `None`, the `chars` argument defaults to removing whitespace. The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped

`strip` on a `str` removes leading and trailing whitespace, so `"  abc  "` becomes `"abc"`, for instance.